# Get data from Message by MessageId or Index

Tags: client-library

I use iota/Cliente, to submit a message with some data from a json file.
Now i try to get this data using getMessage() with the messageId or Index.

I try this:

```
const client = new ClientBuilder().build();

const message = await client.getMessage().data("ddd5a550d5df1094e7badddd8a857f64d15a708f1972c81d7a88fbcc8f9b2170")
console.log(message);
```

But only get information from the message, childs, network etc but no data.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is inside of the indexation payload, you can get it like this

```
    const message = await client.getMessage().data("ddd5a550d5df1094e7badddd8a857f64d15a708f1972c81d7a88fbcc8f9b2170")
    const decoded = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(message.message.payload.data.data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(decoded), null, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks men, it work well when i use it in a simple node project. But when i try it in a node API Express project (I'm working now) i have a json error:

 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

It's the same, any idea?